# (PostgreSQL) Stored Procedure to move data from Table1 to Table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would you move all the data in Table1 to Table2 on PostgreSQL using a stored procedure when Table1 and Table2 have different column names (cannot simply JOIN).
Assume both tables are already made in the DB and the purpose is once data from Table1 is moved to Table2, Table1 gets wiped (using a trigger?), and assume Table2 is blank before any data is moved from Table1.

Please refer to image below for a simplified example.

Was thinking using a cursor in some way or form. Would that be efficient?

Much thanks!

[Click for image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKtaR.png)

Comment: `insert into table2 (...) select ... from table1`

Comment: FYI, do not use images for textual information, see [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) . Copy and paste the text into your question.